# Jquery Dialog Button to Call An Action Method with parameter

Tags: jquery

Please I need help with a jQuery dialog functionality. Code of various sections is shown below.

Here is the code for the actionLink  select button

```
Html.ActionLink("Select", "EditExistingReferral", "UnresolvedItems", new { unresolvedReferralId = item.Id }, new { @class = "selectReferral" })
```

When this 'select' button is clicked, I want a dialog to display. Here is the code for the jQuery dialog.

```
$(function DisplaySystemMessage() {
    $('.selectReferral').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#system-message').dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 400,
            height: 'auto',
            buttons: {
                "Continue": function () {
                    var href = $('.selectReferral').attr('href');
                    //alert(href);

                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });

        //if its referral - open dialog
        $('#system-message').dialog('open');
    });
});
```

when the 'continue' dialog button is clicked, I want the following action method to be called with the apprioriate parameter:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EditExistingReferral(string unresolvedReferralId) {
    int existingReferralId = int.Parse(unresolvedReferralId);
        ....      
}
```

Please how do I get the right parameter when the 'select' button is clicked so I can pass it to the EditExistingReferral action method when the 'continue' dialog button is clicked?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current approach:

`var href = $('.selectReferral').attr('href');`

will always get the first instance of class `selectReferral` which will NOT get the appropriate ID value for you (except when you click the first instance).

Instead, get the HREF of the link that was just clicked and place it into a variable (put the following after `e.preventDefault();`)

`var destinationHref = $(this).attr("href");`

and then you can use this variable inside of the Continue function.

Try it out with your `Alert` to see that the href/id values are as expected.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to return a new view from the action method than

```
$(location).attr('href', href);
```

should do it.

However, since you are already clicking the link to trigger the dialog, a more elegant solution would be to just allow the event to occur if the Continue button is clicked and only perform

```
e.preventDefault();
```

if the Cancel button is clicked.

I should caveat the above solution with it will depend on how your RouteConfig is setup.  It will work if you have a route configured to extract the unresolvedReferralId, such as

```
{controller}/{action}/{unresolvedReferralId}
```